# Broken Clock is Right twice a day

Tags: java

I recently took a hacker challenge question, I got 5/9 outputs correct, the 4 that were wrong were hidden but my best guess is it occurred if my function values were actual float variables.

Here is the question:

> There is an old saying that a broken clock is right twice a day. if
>   the clock is stoped at 1:20 then it will be right at 1:20am and
>   1:20pm, write a function that accepts:
>
> - The Rate `r` of the broken clock's second hand. Every second a normal clock moved, the broken clock will move `r` seconds (neg is
>     backwards)
> - the hours elapsed
>
> Example
>
> ```
> rate = 0  
> elapsed hours = 24  
> result = 2
> ```
>
> The function you are given to work on:
>
> ```
> static int CountCorrectDisplay(float rate, float elapsedhours)
> ```

What I got was this:

```
class Solution {
    static int CountCorrectDisplay(float rate, float elapsedhours) {
        int result = 0;
        float[] rateNormal = new float[(int) elapsedhours];
        float[] rateBroken = new float[(int) elapsedhours];

        for (int i = 0; i < rateNormal.length; i++) {
            rateNormal[i] = i % 12;

            if (rate >= 0) {
                rateBroken[i] = (rate * rateNormal[i]) % 12;
            } else if (rate < 0) {
                rateBroken[i] = (Math.abs(rate + 24) * rateNormal[i]) % 12;
            }

            if (rateNormal[i] == rateBroken[i]) {
                result++;
            }

            System.out.println("Mult: " + rateNormal[i]);
            System.out.println("Rate: " + rateBroken[i]);
            System.out.println();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(CountCorrectDisplay(12, 24));
    }
}
```

The errors being if you place float values like 1.15, 12.5
What I most likely did not account for if the elapsed time was a float value. And if I try it over coderpad I get a warning telling me conversion might not be the same.

1. Am I correct in assuming the 4 cases that were wrong are when float values are taken into account
2. How would I approach this problem to account for float values into the function
3. If the float value scenario is not the issue, what am I doing wrong in my code

**Edit**
One of the errors was an Out of Bounds. I am guessing this is because if the elapsed hours is 12.5, I need to have 1 extra element size for my array. I need some logic to check if elapsedhours has decimal values greater than 0, than I can add one to the size of my arrays.

I also see that I need to convert my decimal value to time. Most likely the decimal value will be a % of 60. So 12.5, take the .5 and take 50% of 60 minutes giving you 30 minutes. I am thinking similar logic for rate (in seconds-miliseconds)

Comment: Are you sure it didn't fail on memory or time? Your algorithm is not as efficient as possible for very large values of `elapsed_hours`

Comment: Hmm, I don't believe so but it has been a few days. If I am not mistaken both the Time Complexity and Auxiliary Space are both O(n), and yes with large values I can fail on memory. Any suggestions on how to improve memory usage, HashMap instead of my 2 arrays?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can get to O(1) with this.

Comment: Hmm, would a Hasmap count as O(1) Auxiliary space if I know the size of the key set can never grow over 24 items?